# Customize a UITableViewCell highlighted style

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am confused about how to custom a `UITableViewCell` highlighted style, not only the highlighted cell background color, but also the frame of its subviews(an imageview)?

The

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
```

method doesn't work for me. If I only change the highlighted color of the cell, it works very well. But it doesn't work for changing the frame of cell's subviews.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: are you adding a custom view on contentView of the tableview cell ?

Comment: also check for @property(nonatomic) UITableViewCellSelectionStyle selectionStyle property in your cellforRowAtIndex and try various styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by following way

below is Sample code for it

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *strIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:strIdentifier];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(278, 2, 40, 40)];
    [imgv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    imgv.tag = 100 + indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgv];

    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell: %d",indexPath.row]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d - %03d",indexPath.section, indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

---

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    //set the frame of subview on highlight
    UIImageView *imgv = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100+indexPath.row];
    [imgv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [imgv setFrame:CGRectMake(238, 2, 80, 40)];
}
```

---

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    //now reset the frame of subview on Unhighlight
    UIImageView *imgv = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100+indexPath.row];
    [imgv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [imgv setFrame:CGRectMake(278, 2, 40, 40)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best to just use the delegate protocols:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
// and
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Then just make the adjustments directly to your UITableViewCell via `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellforRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`.